# What has happened to the function "grid.draw"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to use the function `grid.draw` when making a plot in ggplot2, but I got an error message:

```
could not find function "grid.draw"
```

Is this function defunct? Has it been replaced?

Answer (score 11):

`grid.draw` has always been in the `grid` package (Recommended, hence included with most R distributions)

Comment: Warning message:
package ‘grid’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: @SLevin; Are you tying to install it? - (there is no need to). You should be able to load it with `library('grid')`

Comment: Or you call the function directly with grid::grid.draw()